# Programmatic centering autolayout does not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, center

There is a view named parentView; I want it laid out in the center of superview. Code is below.

When I added the code and compiled, nothing was different— The code had no effect?

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary=@{@"parentView":_parentView};

[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_parentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[parentView(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[parentView(==222)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: what now is displayed is same with i didn't add the code.

Comment: this may be silly, but.. do you call `[self.view addSubView:_parentView]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert the following line in the beginning, I assume `parentView` is a view in the storyboard defined as `IBOutlet`.

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

Comment: Thanks very much,it's ok.But i can't understand why i should add the  code,and i search the IB,there is no constraint on the parentView.So why?

Comment: Did you see the error message? It says can't satisfy all constraints, even if you don't set any constraint for the parentView in storyboard, Xcode will create constraints for you that are type of IBGeneratedContraints, and you also set constraints for parentView, they conflict with the IBGeneratedContraints, which are removed by the above code and thus you can add your own.